# Get access to loaded file by angle bracket parameter

Tags: python, redirect, input, parameters

I have file loadMe.txt that i want to use in my script main.py. To do so I execute script from command line by command:

```
python main.py < loadMe.txt
```

How can I access to this loadMe.txt in my script in this "<" way? Also how operator "<" is named?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` is called "input redirection". It uses the file as an input source. You can think of `cmd < file` as equivalent to `cat file | cmd`.

In Python, there are a variety of ways to read from it. A basic `input()` command will read until a new line. You can also do something like this:

```
import sys

# use `sys.stdin` like the file.

whole_contents = sys.stdin.read()
# Or something like
first_five_chars = sys.stdin.read(5)
```